# powershell: you must provide a value expression on the right hand side of the '-' operator

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get domain name of remote computer.
Below is my WMI Query which i am using.
If i ran this script locally then i am getting the domain name.

```
$domain= (gwmi WIN32_ComputerSystem).Domain
```

but if i want to get the details of remote machine by using below script.

```
$domain= (gwmi WIN32_ComputerSystem).Domain -ComputerName $machinename
```

Then i am getting this error.

**you must provide a value expression on the right hand side of the '-' operator**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why that particular error happens, I see `Unexpected token '-computername' in expression or statement` which makes more sense, but the answer is to add the `ComputerName` parameter as part of the call to the cmdlet:

```
$domain = (gwmi WIN32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $machinename).Domain
```

Comment: In OP's case, `-ComputerName` is probably being interpreted as a sutraction operator (minus) and the command name "Computername" (which is, of course, not a valid value expression for a subtraction operation)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am testing it now.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen that makes sense, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I am trying to get ip address by this $IPAdd = Test-Connection $$ -count 1 | select Ipv4Address and it is showing in console but when i try to export it to csv i am getting system.object. Can you please advise on this? It is not looking good to raise a new question for this.

Comment: use `Test-Connection $$ -count 1 | select -ExpandProperty Ipv4Address`